# Meshing ring networks with minimum extra edges

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have several datasets in my problem that could reasonably be grouped as ring networks, and in order to display them most appealingly, I want to combine them in a way that minimizes the number of edges:

[image: These three ring networks combine to form a united network with reused connections, optimizing the graph's appearance.]

The problem is super easy for two: simply put all of the shared nodes next to each other and let the others loop around back. It's also simple for 3 or less nodes in a network, because the order doesn't matter. But how do I solve the problem for 3 networks or more, with 4 or more nodes in them?

Because the data in each ring is unordered, I can reorder it for maximum efficiency. How can I ensure the minimum number of edges in these combined ring networks given an arbitrary set of ring networks like this one?

**EDIT:** Code in which this is used:

```
function arrangeInLoops (sets) {

    /* sort sets for maximum edge overlap */

    var graph = new Graph();

    for (var i = 0; i < sets.length; i++) {
        for (var j = sets[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            // Both of these methods are made idempotent
            graph.addNode(sets[i][j]);
            graph.addEdge(sets[i][j], sets[i][j > 0 ? j - 1 : sets[i].length - 1]);
        }
    }

    return graph;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems are you having? (If this is merely a challenge, then stack-overflow is the wrong place. Checkout http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) If this is not a challenge for the community, is this per-chance a homework assignment? (I apologize for my bluntness, but as I am understanding your problem, neither of these categories are suitable for stack overflow.)

Comment: @ChrisBritt This is an application for work - the items being displayed in this way are business entities, and I'm trying to create an easy non-keyboard centric way of visualizing them.

Comment: Ok, Is the display you have now in the question what your current program is outputting and you want to change it? (If so how specifically do you want to change the output) The graph doesn't appear to have any redundancies that I can see. If the graph is the output you want to have, what are you currently trying? (If its work related, I understand if you can't post your current source, but can you try and develop a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?)

Comment: @ChrisBritt PPCG isn't a site for programming questions. Please don't direct users who are asking for help there; it's a very different site from the rest of the network, where "questions" aren't really questions but challenges/contests. Thanks, your friendly neighborhood PPCG moderator :)

Comment: @Doorknob冰 I know its not for programming questions, but rather challenges. However, how his question was originally phrased prior to any editing, it appeared that he was in fact posing a challenge to develop the "best" algorithm to complete his task, as opposed to having a question about completing the task. As I obviously mis-interpreted his intention, I offer my sincere apologies to all offended parties.

Comment: @ChrisBritt Thank you. I guess I was desperate a few days ago - the way I ended up asking the question to CodeGolf was a little underhanded, and I'm sorry for that as well. I'm not as desperate anymore because I've found a better solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found my own solution for displaying these data sets better: Since the data are fundamentally unordered and are fundamentally about some kind of relationship, simply connect all the items in each set to each other (i.e. create a *complete* graph instead of a ring network). That way, instead of figuring out where meshes should happen yourself, you can allow whatever polynomial-time force-directed algorithm you're using to calculate them for you, since they'll get suspended between the two sets they belong to.